# How many types of urls are out there?

Tags: url, twitter4j

I am working on a project where I need to filter the tweets which contain URLs. Now, I am using following text.

```
  boolean tweetContainsURL= 
   tweetText.contains("http://") 
|| tweetText.contains("https://") 
|| tweetText.contains("t.co")
|| tweetText.contains("bit.ly") 
|| tweetText.contains("</a>");
```

How many types of URLs are actually out there? 
(Just recently I found out fb.me URLs)

Comment: Theoretically, the number is bound only by the maximum length of an URL (limited by length of a Tweet in this case), to the Nth power where N is the number of legal Unicode characters in a URL. Perhaps you need to focus your question more.

Comment: Those aren't URLs. They're protocol names, domain names, and html tags.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would specifically apply this to Twitter4J, but the Twitter API includes lists of various "entities" within a Tweet.  [One of the kinds of entities it keeps track of is URLs](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects#urls).  So you could enumerate through those URLs and use String.replace to remove each one.